# Automating the creation of Homedrive of a newly created AD user

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have made a script to create a homefolder(by the name of SAMAccountname) for a newly created AD user.

```
$ADServer = 'xyz1'

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$searchbase = "OU=xyz2,OU=xyz3,DC=xyz4,dc=xyz5"

$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq "xyz6"} -Server $ADServer -SearchBase $searchbase -Properties *

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "xyz7\$($ADUsers.sAMAccountname)"
```

Everything is automated except the fact that I have to feed in the name of the user (AD account name) to make it search for that particular user.
I want to change this process. I want to make this automated thru a scheduled run.

Now, I want to query the eventlog and search for `EVENTID = 4720` (ie "a new user is created") and trap the `SamAccountName` of this newly created user (under attributes [I have checked]) and pass this in my current script... so that if I run the overall script by scheduled run, it will detect the new user creation and automatically make its homefolder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = (Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 514}).message
```

Should allow you to get back the information you want. You can then split the result to parese out the SAM name.

"514" is just my example - you'll need to replace that with what ever EventID you want to track.

[linky](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176846.aspx)
Has more info on how to use get-eventlog to filter the results

Comment: it is not usefull, I want to extract that SAMACCOUNTNAME and save it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

For extracting the account names created within the last 30 minutes you could use a regular expression like this:

```
Get-EventLog Security -Computer SERVERNAME -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) |
  Where-Object {
    $_.EventID -eq 4720 -and
    $_.Message -match "sam account name:\s+(.*)"
  } | ForEach-Object { $matches[1] }
```

With that said, an ultimately better approach would be to integrate home directory creation in the user creation process, i.e. create the directory when you create the user (since you already have the account name at that point).

Comment: With that said, an ultimately better approach would be to integrate home directory creation in the user creation process, i.e. create the directory when you create the user (since you already have the account name at that point).

I liked your point, but how to do this, can u kick me in the right direction? or pls provide a sample code to support ur point....

otherwise keeping the same code, how to make this time restricted, so that homedirectory for one user maybe created only once....

Comment: By scripting the whole user creation process you can easily run `New-Item` after `New-ADUser`. As for restricting the time frame: please [do some legwork yourself](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849834%28v=wps.620%29.aspx), will you?

Comment: actually the new user is created by the help desk guy at anytime in the world, so i cant change this process...cant write a script for creating new ad user - as this wud be manual... 

so i think i cnt do anything in this respect...? or can I? pls suggest

Comment: If you can't get the process changed then no, there's not much you could do about getting this right.

Comment: right... ! so i think i have to stick to creating a time restriction, can u pls help integrate it with my present script

Comment: I already referred you to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx) (although in the wrong language, as I just noticed, sorry about that). You need something like `-After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: Okay, one more thing!
the AD is in different server, and script is to be run on the server on which the home drive is to created, so the query that u suggested should have input of the AD server details....
how to input that?
I tried -computername and -source, but its useless!

Comment: `-ComputerName` should work. If it doesn't, try running the command remotely via [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx).

Comment: Ok! sorry, I tried -computername again and it worked!!! :D

So, whatever left is bounding it so that it does'nt end up creating homedrive for the same user forever.

So, -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) .... how will this work pls explain, you hv helped a lot, pls query this last thing for me!

Comment: I'm willing to help, but I'm not going to read the documentation to you. Please read it yourself (and experiment a little to get a feeling for how things work).

Comment: I have read it & understood it, but what is pesting me is this -  the AD can be created at anytime in world any number of times by the help desk(no pattern to it), and i want to run this script every 30 mins and just to ensure that nobody is left. are u getting? so, what can i do in this situation...

Comment: Obviously you need to restrict the time frame to the last 30 minutes then (`(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)`). If you want to be on the safe side you could make the interval a little bigger (35 or 40 minutes, so you have some overlap) and skip home directories that have already been created.

Comment: right, but the expression you mentioned would only fetch te latest user's accountname in the last 30 mins... I want accountname of every user created in this last interval

Comment: If you don't want just the first result, then don't select just the first result. I thought that was fairly obvious. Please use your brain. I'm not going to spoon-feed a solution to you. This is my final response to this question.

Comment: $ADServer = 'xyz'
$a = (Get-EventLog Security -computername $ADServer -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720}).count
if($a -ge 1)
{
 
 $c = Get-EventLog Security -computername $ADServer | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720 -and $_.Message -match "sam account name:\s+(.*)"} | ForEach-Object { $matches[1] } | Select-Object -First 50

 foreach($b in $c)
 {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "abc\$b"
 } 
}
else
{
 Exit-PSSession
}

Comment: this is giving an error - illegal characters in path