# passing string variable in New-item -path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was writing this code to capture newly created AD's samaccountname and make a homefolder for it ! im facing this issue -

```
$ADServer= 'xyz'

$c = Get-EventLog Security -computername $ADServer -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 4720 -and $_.Message -match "sam account name:\s+(.*)"} | ForEach-Object { $matches[1] } | Select-Object -First 1

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\abc\$c"
```

this is showing error - illegal characters in string, how can I create the folder of the same thing I captured in `$c` ?

Comment: What does `$c` contain? I suspect it is currently an object, therefore you may need to select the specific property for this to work

Comment: $c contains the samaccountname of the newly created AD user (U can check this in eventlog for eventid - 4720)

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the entire output to the console when you type `$c`? If it is displayed in a table show what the columns are.

Comment: no, typing $c gives just the samaccountname - i mean no table , no nothing, just the string

and the error is 

new-item : illegal characters in path.
InvalidArgument : (\\abc\xyz:string)

Comment: So what is the entire path then? Simplifying to `\\abc\xyz` might not be sufficient here if you're having this issue. You need to show exactly what these variables contain. Does it work if you manually run the `New-Item` command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automating the creation of Homedrive of a newly created AD user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721386/automating-the-creation-of-homedrive-of-a-newly-created-ad-user)

Comment: \\10.192.34.10\F$\$c  is the path.

$c contains MartinDummy

Comment: its nt duplicate, its a seperate issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\abc\c$\$($c.Trim())"
```

or:

```
$c = $c.trim()
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\abc\$c"
```

> The Reason: You have extra space letter at the end, this is why it fails,

Use the `$c.trim()` or `$c -replace "\s"` to remove the the space char

Comment: GREAT! this is the answer, thanks! sheesh, how did I miss that!

Comment: `trim()` would be better than your `-replace` here since there could be legitimate spaces in the path. You could do   `-replace "\s+$"` just in case.

Comment: That's a good point but in the scenario of SAMAccountName Space is not an option